# Where can I find some information about Nathanael besides John 1?

Tags: gospel-of-john, disciple

In John 1:46-50, Nathanael is introduced to Jesus for the first time.

We know He was Philip's friend from Bethsaida and He was "truly an Israelite in whom there is no deceit"

Where can I find some information about Nathanael besides John 1?
Any passage or book, biography, [site](http://www.bibliapage.com/apostolo.html)...

Comment: He is also mentioned at the end of the Gospel ([John 21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2021&version=NIVUK)) where he is going fishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nathaniel in the New Testament was a good friend of the Apostle Philip's and became one of Jesus' Apostles later on. He is only seen with the name Nathaniel in the Gospel of John but in the Gospels of Matthew, Mark and Luke, he is mentioned under the name of Bartholomew. He witnessed the majority of Jesus' ministry along with his death and resurrection. Afterwards, it is thought that he was a missionary to India, and was eventually flayed and crucified for his testimony the Jesus' life and teachings.